# Как сделать обратный переход через UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

у меня на FirstViewControlle.xib 
есть кнопка info при нажатии на которую я перехожу на info.xib 
как сделать обратный переход через UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp, т.к обратный переход происходит обычным способом (слево на право)

```
-(IBAction)info //кнопка перехода на info.xib
{
    InfoViewController *ivc = [[InfoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBtn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"to first" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem]setBackBarButtonItem:backBtn2];

 //переход   
[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, избавляйтесь от старого синтаксиса, уже давно для этой анимации используются методы типа

```
[UIView transitionFromView:fView
                        toView:tView
                      duration:deration
                       options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

или

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         /* do your animations here */
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

рекомендованные Apple как замена конструкции `UIView +beginAnimations:context: +commitAnimations` после введения блоков

во-вторых, для осуществления кастомных переходов в `UINavigationController` существует рекомендованная техника через `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` + `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`

вот есть описание с примерами:

- [iOS 7 Tutorial Series: Custom Navigation Transitions & More](http://captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-7-tutorial-series-custom-navigation-transitions-more)
- [iOS 7 Custom View Controller Transitions and Rotation, making it all work](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/ios-7-custom-view-controller-transitions-and-rotation-making-it-all-work)

очень сильный инструмент поддерживающий push и pop view controller, соответственно, ваша задача сможет быть решена с помощью этого инструмента, также там доступна persent driven transition, чтобы пользователь мог вести пальцем и при этом видеть кастомную анимацию в процессе.

**если не хочется со всем этим заморачиваться, можно попробовать:**

```
[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                                    forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```